# Could not build wheels for Pillow, typed-ast, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, install.packages

I'm trying to run a old project here is my requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.4.1
astroid==2.3.3
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Django==4.0.1
django-cleanup==5.2.0
idna==2.8
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
Pillow==9.0.0
requests==2.22.0
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
sslcommerz-python==0.0.7
typed-ast==1.4.0
tzdata==2021.5
urllib3==1.25.7
wrapt==1.11.2
```

after asking chatgpt i've also downloaded windows software development kit with microsoft visual c++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64, x86).
here are the packages that already exists in my venv

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.3.2
setuptools 65.5.0
typed-ast  1.5.5
wheel      0.42.0
```

i tried to run both command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt --use-pep517
```

but the error occurs

```
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for typed-ast
Failed to build Pillow typed-ast
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, typed-ast, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

ask me if any other info is needed.

Comment: i'm using python 3.11.1

Answer (score 1):

Pillow 9.0 supports Python 3.7-3.10:

- https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#python-support

This means there are no precompiled binary wheels for Python 3.11, so pip is downloading the source code and attempting to build from source.

I recommend against building from source on Windows, it requires setting up a compiler which can be tricky.

Instead, I suggest either using Pillow 9.3+ with Python 3.11, or using Python 3.10 with Pillow 9.0.

Similarly, if using a newer Python than originally used for the old project, you may find some other requirements also need to be upgraded; or to use the same, older Python version originally used for the old project.

Comment: I used python3.9 for the project and now using python3.11 that's why. I figured it out and it worked for me. Does pillow has to do anything with typed-ast or wheel? if i choose python3.11 and PIllow9.3, what version do i choose for typed-ast?

Comment: Pillow doesn't depend on typed-ast or wheel, although if you're building from source, it might need wheel for that. One way to check if a package supports a Python version is to check PyPI, for example https://pypi.org/project/typed-ast/1.4.0/ says 3.5-3.8 in the left menu. It might support later, but we can't be sure. The first one that explicitly supports 3.11 is https://pypi.org/project/typed-ast/1.5.5/